# Errores en formulario de login

Tags: sql, mysqli, login, dreamweaver

He hecho una página con Dreamweaver que tiene una zona de acceso privado para que el administrador del sitio pueda añadir contenidos que se ven en la parte pública. La pruebo en local y todo funciona bien.

Sin embargo, tras haber pasado todo a MySQLi (y haber comprobado que funciona en local), haber actualizado los datos de las conexiones con la bbdd remota (se conecta bien) y  haberla subirla al servidor, me encuentro con un problema.

Mi archivo de acceso se llama: `MCC_aeb.php`

Aparecen estos 2 mensajes de error que hacen referencia a mi servidor local:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /homepages/27/d741383808/htdocs/admin/MCC_aeb.php on line 64
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /homepages/27/d741383808/htdocs/admin/MCC_aeb.php on line 64

---

Que remiten a mi servidor local... ¡Pero los archivos están en el servidor remoto!

Pego a continuación el código de conexión a la bbdd:

```
$host_name_remota = 'mihostname';
$database_remota = 'mibbdd';
$user_name_remota = 'miusuario';
$password_remota = 'mipassword';
$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name_remota, $user_name_remota, $password_remota, $database_remota);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die('<p>Error al conectar con servidor MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error().'</p>');
} else {
echo '<p>Se ha establecido la conexión al servidor MySQL con éxito.</p >';
}
```

Por supuesto, lleva las etiquetas de apertura y cierre de php.

A continuación, pego el código del archivo del login que, como dije, se llama MCC_aeb.php:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}
if (PHP_VERSION >= 7) {     // SI la versión de PHP es mayor o igual a 7.
global $remota;        // Hago global la variable 
}

// global $remota;
//$theValue = function_exists("mysqli_real_escape_string") ?  mysqli_real_escape_string($remota, $theValue) : mysqli_escape_string($remota,$theValue);
switch ($theType) {
case "text":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
$_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

 if (isset($_POST['mail'])) {
$loginUsername=$_POST['mail'];
$password=$_POST['csign'];
$MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
$MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "edicion.php";
$MM_redirectLoginFailed = "MCC_error.php";
$MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;


$LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT u_email, u_password FROM usuarios WHERE u_email=%s AND u_password=%s",
GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

$LoginRS = mysqli_query($remota, $LoginRS__query) or die(mysqli_error($remota));
$loginFoundUser = mysqli_num_rows($LoginRS);
if ($loginFoundUser) {
$loginStrGroup = "";

if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
//declare two session variables and assign them
$_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
}
header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
}
else {
header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
}
}
?>
<?php require_once('../Connections/remota.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>MCC_aeb</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
<style type="text/css">
@import url("../estilos/MCC_desktop_02.css")screen and (min-width:1024px);

@import url("../estilos/MCC_tablet_02.css")screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1023px);


@import url("../estilos/MCC_movil_02.css")screen and (max-width:767px);


.centrado-porcentual {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
width:400px;
height:auto;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.centrado-porcentual img{
padding-left:25px;
padding-bottom:50px;
}
table{
margin-top: 50px 0;
widith:400px;   
}
td{
padding:20px 10px;
}
input{
font-size:1.1em;
}
.espaciar_btn{
margin: 0 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="centrado-porcentual">
<img src="../imgs/Logo_MCC_RGB.jpg"  alt="Logo" style="margin:0 auto ;" />
    <div style="padding:20px; margin-top:30px auto; border:#9CB65F dotted 1px; text-align:center;">
    <form id="Acceso" name="Acceso" method="POST" action="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>">

    <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
<tr>
    <td width="133" align="right" valign="top">Correo electrónico</td>
    <td width="243" align="left" valign="top">
        <label for="mail"></label>
        <input name="mail" type="text" id="mail" size="20" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">Contraseña</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">
        <label for="csign"></label>
        <input name="csign" type="password" id="csign" size="15" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center" valign="top">
<input name="Acceder" type="submit" value="Acceder" class="espaciar_btn" />     
<input name="Restablecer" type="reset" value="Restablecer" class="espaciar_btn"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>  
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Siento que el código sea tan largo.

Muchas gracias por la lectura y, si es posible, por una respuesta.

Un saludo

Comment: Hola José. Gracias por contestar. Ahora mismo no puedo acceder al ordenador para probar con la idea que aportas: mañana a primera hora lo intento. Pero sí te comento que $remota es el nombre de mi conexión.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es con la variable $remote usada en mysqli_query, esa variable tiene un valor NULL. si consultas en el manual de PHP el primer parametro de mysqli_query debe ser la variable que contiene el enlace con la base de datos, teniendo en cuenta eso debes hacer:

Usar la variable $connect y no $remote

```
$LoginRS = mysqli_query($connect, $LoginRS__query) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
```

El require_once debes hacerlos antes de la consulta a la base de datos y no despues, como lo tienes ahi. Por ejemplo:

```
require_once('../Connections/remota.php');//Aquí colocas el require_once para que $connect este definida.

$LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT * FROM usuarios",
GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 
$LoginRS = mysqli_query($connect, $LoginRS__query) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
```

Asegúrate de colocar el require_once en el lugar correcto, para que no tengas inconvenientes por usar session_start().

Con eso debería ser suficiente para que te deje de dar es problema. Quedo atento.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, José. Ahora mismo no puedo acceder al ordenador pero te respondo desde el móvil. $remota es el nombre de mi conexión. Mañana a primera hora lo pruebo y te digo algo. Gracias de nuevo. Saludos.

Comment: Hola de nuevo y gracias por la lectura y la atención, José Meléndez.

Verás, anoche te comenté que mi conexión se llama remota, de ahí la variable $remota. 

He movido el require_once de sitio, ahora, además de informarme que sobre si se conecta o no a la bbdd (que se conecta, como puede verse) me da otro mensaje:

Se ha establecido la conexión al servidor MySQL con éxito.

Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /homepages/27/d741383808/htdocs/admin/MCC_aeb.php on line 48 

Me extraña que el Warning remita a mi stio local en htdocs. Gracias.

Comment: Ok, eso es porque estas enviando cabeceras antes del iniciar la sesión. Coloca el session_start al principio de todo (todo require_once, include_once, include, require debe estar por debajo del session_start, pero por arriba de donde usar las variables de conexion a la base de datos)

Answer (score 0):

José. Un saludo.

He movido el require_once al principio y sigue pasando lo mismo. Me da ese error

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /homepages/27/d741383808/htdocs/admin/MCC_aeb.php on line 48

La línea 48 del código a la que se refiere es:

```
session_start();
```

Pero sigo sin entender por qué el error hace referencia a mis archivos locales: yo probé la web en local y funcionaba perfectamente. El problema lo tengo al conectarla al servidor remoto donde estoy trabajando en una carpeta particular que no tiene repercusión en la web.

No sé. Quizá el problema esté en la conexión con el sitio remoto: como que hay algo que no acaba de estar bien y por eso los errores me remiten a local...

Gracias una vez más. Saludos.